# Cargar vista en un modal con Ajax con twig

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, modal, twig

tengo un problema. No me carga en ajax el contenido dinámico.  Lo que quiero cargar es un formulario para modificar datos.

La url del route (el  202032 será dinámico cuando cargue bien):

```
$router->map( 'GET', '/admin/registros/modificar/202032/','empresaControllerAdmin#Modificar','Modificar Registro');
```

Si llamo desde el navegador a la URL dominio.com/temporal/admin/registros/modificar/202032/ **me lo carga bien**. Entra en el controlador y me muestra la vista correctamente, pero **si la llamo desde jquery/ajax, NO.**

El index donde proceso todo lo tengo en:

temporal/index.php

Y el js está en

> **temporal/themes/admin/js/archivo.js**

Cuando hago la llamada a la función, el navegador se encuentra en

> **temporal/admin/inicio/**   (por eso meto los ../../ para bajar a temporal/ y que desde ahí ejecute la petición GET para pasarla por el enrutador y después ejecute el controlador.)

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#submit02").mousedown(function(){
        $('#ModalDinamico').modal({show:true});
        cargarContenido();
      });
    });

    function cargarContenido(){  
            var url = "../../admin/registros/modificar/202032/";
            $.ajax({                        
               type: "GET",                 
               url: url,                     
               //data: $("#formutareas").serialize(), 
               success: function(data)             
               { 
                 $('#bodyModalDetalles').html(data);               
               }
           });
    };
```

Modal detalle:

```
<!-- Modal Detalle -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalDinamico" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalDinamicoTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Detalle</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="bodyModalDetalles">Cargando...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>  
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

En Console me sale esto:

```
  jquery.min.js:2 GET http://www.dominio.com/temporal/admin/registros/modificar/202032/ 404 (Not Found)
send    @   jquery.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:2
cargarContenido @   varios.js:11
(anonymous) @   varios.js:4
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:2
v.handle    @   jquery.min.js:2
```

​

Pero si copio y entro en esta URL si me entra.
​

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no carga, el valor de `data` que asignas en `done`?  ¿Hiciste un `console.log(data);` en esa parte, para ver si el servidor está devolviendo algo realmente? ¿Por qué no pones también la función `fail` de Ajax para ver si no hay errores? Por otra parte, no estoy seguro que te reconozca una url pasada así desde Ajax: `../../admin/registros/modificar/202032/` prueba poniendo la URL completa.

Comment: En console me pone GET http://www.dominio.com/temporal/admin/registros/modificar/202032// 404 (Not Found)  pero si entro por navegador, si existe la ruta.  PD: donde lo he modificado por success pero tampoco va.

Comment: No tienes que modificarlo por `success`. Ten en cuenta que `success` queda obsoleto y preferible usar `done`. Por lo demás, veo que ya lo resolviste. Siempre haz la prueba por consola porque te da indicaciones del error, como pudiste ver de inmediato, era un error 404 debido a un problema de ruta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he localizado el fallo, en el index.php estaba arrojando un if de comprobación mal hecho 404, lo he quitado y me va. Utilizo **Altorouter**.

```php
<?php 
    if( is_array($match) && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {
        call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] ); 
    } else  {
        // no route was matched
        echo "Ha sucedido un error";
        //header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
    } 

 ?>
```